# Flink CPU configuration

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Official Flink Documentation states that for each core in your cpu, you have to allocate 1 slot and increase the parallelism level by one simultaneously.

One of my custom operators requires more than 1 CPU for computing (It is how it works in Heron). My system's cpu is 2.5. But Flink only uses 1 cpu. Do you know how can I config the Flink to use more CPU with only 1 slot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63545425/2000823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One slot per core" is merely a rule of thumb. Nothing enforces this.

Each subtask (an instance of an operator chain) is single-threaded, but the slots within a task manager, and the task managers within a machine or container, will use all of the resources made available to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one slot, but a multi-thread operation in your flink code

for example in scala,

```
env.setParallelism(1)
class myMap extends RichMapFunction {
  override def map(...) = {
    data.toParArray()... // this is scala concurrent collection, other language has similar ones, like c/cpp OMP, java multi-thread
  }
}
```

then the flink operator has parallelism of 1, but the internal parallelism is controlled by your `map` method.